# Why doesn't my Shared Excel 365 sheet allow VBA buttons to work in the webpage version of the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

My whole team uses Office 365. This is my first attempt using the online sharing 'co-authoring' feature in 365. I created a 5-6 person, team-use Excel spreadsheet as an ongoing check-off log for a common task. I put in VBA "Done" buttons for when a team member finishes a task.

The file is on our company's OneDrive online folder (which I read was a requirement for co-authoring to work), but when opened in a web-browser the macro buttons are disabled -see screenshot.  The VBA button macros come back and work great only when a user clicks "Open in Desktop App" and works it directly from the app -see 2nd screenshot.

Is there a way for the macro buttons with their VBA code to work in the browser view of the spreadsheet?
[image: Online browser view]
[image: Desktop App of the same file]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Here's my poorly-written macro to show I'm not doing anything fancy with the VBA code:


Sub ButtonH4()
    Dim AccountType, Init As String 
    AccountType = Range("E4").Value
    Init = Range("B7").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("" & AccountType & "").Cells(Range("AA4").Value, 3) = Date
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("" & AccountType & "").Cells(Range("AA4").Value, 4) = Init
End Sub

Comment: VBA does not work on the web app.

Comment: you will need to use Office Scripts, which is a Java Script variant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Comment: @ScottCraner, that's an uphill lift for me, going from VBA to OfficeScripts, from my sample code in the first comment, does it look like an easy thing to translate? And could you point me to the right resource to learn this new script language?

Comment: Ah, I followed the link you included.  I guess that's my resource.  Thank you, Scott!